# Стандартный шейдер Unity не загружается для Addresables ассета

Tags: unity3d, шейдеры

Unity Editor 2022.3.9f1 LTS. Решаю проблему с розовыми текстурами спрайтов в билде под Windows. В логах плеера - утечки памяти, на экране - розовое марево вместо изображений. Возникает в спрайтах объектов, которые загружаются с помощью Addresables. Они используют стандартный шейдер для спрайтов и стандартный материал.
Поискав информацию по теме пришёл к выводу, что стандартные шейдеры, среди которых используемый Sprites/Default, автоматически не подгружаются в бандл ресурсов проекта при сборке, соответственно в рантайме билда происходит зло. Какие есть пути обойти эту *фичу* от юнитеков?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Я нашёл решение. Дело было так: на префабе, который инстанциируется из Addresable, графика для которого и сломана, есть SpriteRenderer. При освобождении handl'a, который этот префаб загружает, почему-то выгружается и материал?шейдер? связанный с рендером префаба. То есть остальные объекты инстанса и сам инстанс остаются в сцене и работают как должны, но материал?шейдер? не считаются системой как ресурсы, на которые есть ссылка, и выгружаются. Очень неочевидное поведение для меня.
Для того чтобы всё заработало, понадобилось убрать выгрузку handl'а префаба после создания его копии. Убрал её в OnDestroy объекта.